# Using HasMany relationship when Model and table have different names

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-6

Like the title says, my Field model and application_fields table have different names. I already set the table name on the Field model to the correct table name. A set the  I have another model, Application, and its controller, ApplicationController. In the index method of the ApplicationController, I am trying to retrieve the application and its fields. The Field model has a belongsTo relationship to Application, and the Application model has a hasMany relationship to Field.

The code seems to work, except it pulls the values for the rows from the applications table. So if the applications table has the following rows:

1 'AppOne' 'An App'

2 'AppTwo' 'Another App'

3 'AppThree' 'A third App'

AppOne, AppTwo, and AppThree are returned as the values for the fields.

Can someone give me some advice?

Here is the code for them( I only copied what was related to the issue, not the entire file):

**Application model:**

```
/**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
protected $table = 'application_fields';

public function fields()
    {
return $this->hasMany('App\Field');
    }
```

**Field model:**

```
public function application()
    {
return $this->belongsTo('App\Application');
    }
```

**ApplicationController:**

```
/**
     * Display the dashboard for a single application.
     *
     * @param String $id
     * @return View
     */
public function show( $id )
    {
$app = Application::where('id', $id)->first();
$fields = $app::with('application_fields')->get();
return view('applications.show', [
'application' => $app,
'fields' => $fields,
        ]);
    }
```

**View( I stripped out the HTML):**

```
{{ $application->name }}
{{ $application->description }}
@foreach($fields as $field)
{{ $field->name}}

 @endforeach
```

I would appreciate any advice on what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your show method is wrong, eager loading does not work that way :)

```php
    public function show( $id ) {

    $app = Application::with('fields')->find($id);
    $fields = $app->fields;
    return view('applications.show', [
        'application' => $app,
        'fields' => $fields,
    ]);
    }
```

you can also use model Binding if your route is like that : `applications/{app}`

```php
    public function show(Application $app) {
    $fields = $app->fields;
    return view('applications.show', [
        'application' => $app,
        'fields' => $fields,
    ]);
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense. But if I use the first show method you provided, I not get "invalid argument supplied for foreach" in the view. So for someone reason my fields are not coming through still.

Comment: My bad I did'nt read the name of your relations, I edited my answer